# JBoss EJB transactions don't generate Oracle SQL Statements from JPA java persistence objetcs (eclipselink)

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jboss

I'm trying to migrate a J2EE heavy application (jnlp) from Oracle OC4j (OAS) using Toplink, to RH JBoss using Eclipselink (without changing functional code of Beans).

If read-only java instructions are correctly translated in a SELECT SQL statement :

```
Session session = getSession();
ReadAllQuery query = new ReadAllQuery(Employee.class);
ExpressionBuilder builder = new ExpressionBuilder();
Expression criteres = builder.get("nom").equal("Smith");
query.setSelectionCriteria(criteres);
Vector employees = (Vector) session.executeQuery(query);
Employee employeeSmith = employees.elementAt(0);
```

==>

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE nom='Smith';
```

But, write java instructions seem not to be translated in corresponding SQL statements :

```
session.acquireUnitOfWork().deleteObject(employeeSmith);
```

==>

```
DELETE employee WHERE nom='Smith';
```

(the same for session.acquireUnitOfWork().registerObject(employeeSmith) doesn't generate neither INSERT nor UPDATE SQL statements)

Is there any setup in JBoss or parameter for Eclipselink to activate this "translation" when EJB commit its transaction ?

**I want to specify that I'm using "native" Oracle JDBC connection protocol with sessions.xml and a XML mapping file (correspondences between Oracle database tables/columns and Java classes/attributes objects), AND NOT persistence units (with persistence.xml definition file and entity managers).**

Thanks a lot in advance for your help and advices.

Regards

*Current configuration :
Oracle OC4j 10.1.3.5.0 using Toplink 11.1.1.2.0 JPA implementation*

*Target configuration :
RedHat JBoss EAP 7.4 using Eclipselink 2.7.0 JPA implementation*

Answer (score 0):

just a quick post to share with the community a way to solve my issue :
in the toplink -> eclipselink migration process, some of connection setup are moved from the Java<->Oracle XML mapping file (XXX.xml) and the **sessions.xml** file :

```xml
<sessions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4.2">
  <session xsi:type="server-session">
    <name>XXX_session</name>
    <logging xsi:type="eclipselink-log">...</logging>
    <primary-project xsi:type="xml">XXX.xml</primary-project>
    <login xsi:type="database-login">...</login>
  </session>
</sessions>
```

I had to add/move the following tags in the **sessions.xml** file :

```xml
<server-platform xsi:type="jboss-platform">
   <enable-jta>true</enable-jta>
</server-platform>
```

and

```
<login xsi:type="database-login">
   <platform-class>org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform</platform-class>
   <external-connection-pooling>true</external-connection-pooling>
   <external-transaction-controller>true</external-transaction-controller>
   <sequencing>
      <default-sequence xsi:type="native-sequence">
         <preallocation-size>1</preallocation-size>
      </default-sequence>
   </sequencing>
   ...
</login>
```

By this way, the write Oracle statements are correctly generated by the JPA provider during the commit phase of the container.

For information, the XSD dictionnary for sessions.xml is :
/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink_sessions_2.1.xsd in eclipselink-2.7.11 library